# Calculating the trait average of each unique animal in a data set using R

Tags: r, unique, average

I have a data set that I need to calculate the trait average of each unique dam and this is an example data set:

```
pig <- c(20111,20112,20113,20571,20572,20573,20584,20585,20586)
sex <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2)
wt <- c(1.54,0.84,0.83,1.14,1.42,1.07,1.25,1.05,1.42)
dam <- c(1661,1661,1661,1027,1027,1027,10331,10331,10331)
res <-c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,2,1)
mt <- c(2,2,2,1,1,NA,1,1,1)
ms <- c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1)
cr <- c(26,24,21,23,25,24,22,22,22)
rt <- c(38.7,37.2,37.8,38.1,38.4,NA,38.1,38,38.3)
data <- data.frame(pig,sex,wt,dam,res,mt,ms,cr,rt)
data
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
udam <- c(1661,1027,10331)
tpig <- c(3,3,3)
asex <- c(1.3,2,1.7)
awt <- c(1.07,1.21,1.24)
ares <- c(1,1,1.33)
amt <- c(2,1,1)
ams <- c(1,1,1)
acr <- c(23.7,24,22)
art <- c(37.6,38.25,38.1)
data2 <- data.frame(udam,tpig,asex,awt,ares,amt,ams,acr,art)
```

I hope that my question is clear enough and any help would be appreciated!

Poasa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `plyr` package has very usefull functions to do this. For example, we can use `ddply` to split a dataframe by a factor, apply a function, and return the results again in a dataframe:

```
    library('plyr')

    ddply(data,.(dam),mean,na.rm=T)

    pig      sex   wt   dam      res mt ms       cr       rt
1 20572 2.000000 1.21  1027 1.000000  1  1 24.00000 38.25000
2 20112 1.333333 1.07  1661 1.000000  2  1 23.66667 37.90000
3 20585 1.666667 1.24 10331 1.333333  1  1 22.00000 38.13333
```

Or use the `summarize` function for a bit more control:

```
ddply(data,.(dam),summarize,
  tpig = 3,
  asex = mean(sex,na.rm=T),
  sexRatio = sum(sex==1)/sum(sex==2),
  awt = mean(wt,na.rm=T),
  ares = mean(res,na.rm=T),
  amt = mean(mt,na.rm=T),
  ams = mean(ms,na.rm=T),
  acr = mean(cr,na.rm=T),
  art = mean(rt,na.rm=T),
  count = length(pig))
    dam tpig     asex sexRatio  awt     ares amt ams      acr      art count
1  1027    3 2.000000      0.0 1.21 1.000000   1   1 24.00000 38.25000     3
2  1661    3 1.333333      2.0 1.07 1.000000   2   1 23.66667 37.90000     3
3 10331    3 1.666667      0.5 1.24 1.333333   1   1 22.00000 38.13333     3
```

Comment: that was really great! You even added the sex ratio which something that has been at the back of my mind for some time. Thank you once again and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
aggregate(cbind(sex, wt, res, mt, ms, cr, rt) ~ dam, data=data, FUN=mean,
  na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)
```

should do the trick for the averages. I assume you want to exclude the NAs from the means for the affected variables, but include the observation otherwise. The counts can be obtained with

```
aggregate(pig ~ dam, data=data, FUN=length)
```